# Won't save the int in coredata swift

Tags: ios, core-data, swift, int

I want to save a Int into my core data, Now i do this this way but it crashes on the Int and only saves 1 item.

```
let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate

let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
let ent = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Groups", inManagedObjectContext: context)

var newItem = Groups(entity: ent!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
```

**My code**

```
if let groups : AnyObject! = json {
    //println(groups["groups"])

    var group = groups["groups"] as NSArray

    for g in group{

        newItem.id = g["id"] as Int
        newItem.name = g["name"] as NSString

        context.save(nil)
        println(newItem)

        println(g["id"] as Int)
        //println(g["name"] as NSString)
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
@objc(Groups)
class Groups: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var id:Int
    @NSManaged var name:String
}
```

[image]

**Consolelog:**

```
nil
<NSManagedObject: 0x7fe0c9f2f520> (entity: Groups; id: 0xd000000000140000 <x-coredata://1405B706-2AC6-4CED-BED5-FE0232723976/Groups/p5> ; data: {
    "group_id" = nil;
    id = 0;
    name = Press;
})
1
<NSManagedObject: 0x7fe0c9f2f520> (entity: Groups; id: 0xd000000000140000 <x-coredata://1405B706-2AC6-4CED-BED5-FE0232723976/Groups/p5> ; data: {
    "group_id" = nil;
    id = 0;
    name = Sales;
})
2
<NSManagedObject: 0x7fe0c9f2f520> (entity: Groups; id: 0xd000000000140000 <x-coredata://1405B706-2AC6-4CED-BED5-FE0232723976/Groups/p5> ; data: {
    "group_id" = nil;
    id = 0;
    name = "Other information";
})
3
```

Comment: Use NSNumber. Int is not an object type in the Core Data ObjectiveC world.

Comment: That won't work tried to change it, but then i get a lldb

Comment: Have you tried to use a int32 instead of 64?

Comment: Then i get a 'AnyObject' is not convertible to Int32

Comment: As matt said, you cannot store a Int in core data, you should save a NSNumber.